# How to enter any input while using kaggle ipython shell commands

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, kaggle, github-cli

[kaggle kernel(photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ1k4.png)

This github cli is asking for inputs

How to send any sort of input?

i tried the thing visible at the attachment